# Upgraded from 2.3.1 to 2.3.3, now billing address drop down is gone from checkout page

Tags: checkout, billing-address, magento2.3.3

I am hoping to get some light here on the issue. After updating from 2.3.1 to 2.3.3 via composer, in the frontend, during checkout page, in the part where the user can change the billing address by unchecking "My Billing and shipping address are the same", the drop down menu with the billing address is no long appearing.[image: Payment Method Section Screenshot]

This behavior affect every payment method that requires a billing address. I have tried to turn off the one page checkout I was using and the behavior is the same. I have consulted with the one-page developer and they told me since the issue persisted with their module disable, the issue is most likely related to theme or static file generation but I do not see any related error log in the system.log or exception.log. The theme is the default luma theme, no changes.

However, in the checkout page, with Chrome web console, it does display some warning:
[image]

I have no clue where the error could be, I have tried to switch from Production mode to Developer mode, redeploy static content, flush cache, clean cache but all doesn't seem to work.

The commands I ran for the upgrade was:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.14.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~3.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:2.4.5 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpmd/phpmd:@stable phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:~3.4.0 --sort-packages --no-update
composer update
bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue was caused by a third party module called "customer attribute system" by x-mage 2, an update from the developer has fixed the issue.